# SharePoint Rest API - not able to get "Form Data" property of a list item

Tags: 2013, office-365, rest, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get a field named "Form Data" using Rest API

I tried the below url

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/sitename/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Items(5581)?$select=FormData
```

I got the below error

```
The field or property 'FormData' does not exist.
```

I am trying to get the unbound property values in Nintex forms using this request as suggested in this [nintex community answers](https://community.nintex.com/thread/7404)

Comment: Does the Field really have the name FormData as you are using in the select? Or is it "Form Data" with a space?

Comment: I tried both, they didn't work

Comment: does the column actually exist ? Can you go to your list settings page and check the column names ? Or you can make a rest call to `https://site.sharepoint.com/sitename/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$select=Title,InternalName` and find out the fields